# port 28060 tcp is related to R?

Tags: r, linux, networking, rstudio

OS is mint 18.2. subset output of netstat -ltnu is below.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:28060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4381          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42155           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:57621           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3061                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

sessionInfo() out:
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 18.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_CA.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_CA.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_CA.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_CA.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_CA.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_CA.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
 [1] qdapRegex_0.7.2     bindrcpp_0.2        openxlsx_4.0.17     gdata_2.18.0        readr_1.1.1         easypackages_0.1.0  readxl_1.0.0        stringr_1.2.0
 [9] dplyr_0.7.4         plyr_1.8.4          data.table_1.10.4-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.14     bindr_0.1        magrittr_1.5     hms_0.4.0        devtools_1.13.4  R6_2.2.2         rlang_0.1.4      tools_3.4.3      withr_2.1.0
[10] gtools_3.5.0     yaml_2.1.15      assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.12    tibble_1.3.4     memoise_1.1.0    glue_1.2.0       stringi_1.1.6    compiler_3.4.3
[19] cellranger_1.1.0 pkgconfig_2.0.1

When I go to 127.0.0.1:28060 it says "Only NEWS and URLs under /doc and /library are allowed" with the R logo at top (forget what that icon is called.. favicon?). I found info via search about a package "Rook". never heard of it.

So is this a legit webserver made by R base (if so, why?)/R package?

Comment: what does `lsof` tell you? Specifically `lsof -i TCP`. Even w/o that, it looks like that's what the R help server bound itself to.

Comment: I killed the process. But if I reboot/see it again I will post the output.

Comment: it appears Rstudio is creating it, rsession 9521    x   15u  IPv4   0t0  TCP localhost:27708 (LISTEN) is the output of lsof -i TCP.

Comment: what I meant to say is you are correct. thanks for identifying that. still, why does R help need to open an incoming connection? wouldn't this just be a typical outgoing connection?

Comment: So, this happens only if your run RStudio and not if your run Rgui? Please tag your question accordingly and add all relevant information to your question.

Comment: Updated. Only in Rstudio, not in standalone R terminal - tried help() and no similar behavior.

Comment: I should also add Rstudio Version 1.1.383.

Comment: R help runs in several different formats. You likely have `getOption("help_type")` set to `"text"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R help system runs an http service on a random port.  You can find the port number for the current session (perhaps starting the service) by calling

```
print(tools::startDynamicHelp(NA))
```

or by running

```
help.start()
```

The latter will start a browser; you can see the port in the URL in the browser (if your browser displays URLs; the built-in one in RStudio doesn't).